# Force HTTPS redirection on whole website except for 1 single page

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

My SSL is managed by cloudFlare but I prefer using htaccess method to control redirection of site to use HTTPS. I have a domain `www.mysite.com` and a sub domain `demo.mysite.com`. I want HTTPS on full website of www.mysite.com and on full website of `demo.mysite.com` as well except for just 1 page on my subdomain to prevent mixed content. That page can contain both HTTP and HTTPS links loaded in iFrame. Currently that page loads in HTTPS along with whole website but I want it to load in HTTP only and not HTTPS. The page is `demo.mysite.com/surf.php` which can be accessed by clicking an Ad at `demo.mysite.com/ads.php`.

I tried this in my htaccess file but the page `surf.php` still redirects to HTTPS.

```
# FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/(surf.php)
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# DISABLE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/(surf.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have disabled "Always use HTTPS" in my cloudFlare settings and my SSL is Flexible. Also, no page rules are set. I prefer htaccess method. Please help me and tell me what to do?

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder how "HTTPS Everywhere" will handle that one.

Comment: Maybe you are lookin at cached 301 redirects? Try clearing browser cache before accessing the http version of your page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still facing trouble then you can also use a PHP code instead. Paste this code on your header file of the website or paste on each page where you want the website to be redirected to HTTPS or HTTP. Make sure to disable "Always use HTTPS" in cloudFlare and you can choose any SSL you want i.e, Flexible, Full or Full (strict).

PHP code for redirecting to HTTPS:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost'){
  if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on'){
    if(!headers_sent()){
      header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
      header(sprintf('Location: https://%s%s',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
      exit();
    }
  }
}
```

PHP code for redirecting to HTTP:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost'){
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
    if(!headers_sent()){
      header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
      header(sprintf('Location: http://%s%s',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
      exit();
    }
  }
}
```

This worked for me pretty well. Paste the code at the top of each page. If you are using `session_start();` then place this code immediately after that. That's a good practice.

Comment: A permanent solution to all my HTTP to HTTPS and vice versa redirection. Thanks a lot. That worked like a charm. I will make sure I never lose this code :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the following working on a domain in Cloudflare that has a flexible Cloudflare cert.

Instead of using .htaccess I have 2 Cloudflare page rules.

The first rule:

```
*.domain.com/page-to-ignore.htm

SSL: Off
```

Second rule:

```
http://*.domain.com/*

Always Use HTTPS
```

The order matters, and when testing on your own site, make sure you have cleared your browser cache.

Hope this helps!

[image]